# wget stuck in the middle of mirroring a webpage

Tags: downloads, wget

I was mirroring a website with the following command:

```
wget -m -nc -p -E -k -np -e robots=off https://www.somesite.com/ & disown
```

And everything was going on alright until I saw that it was stuck in

```
Reusing existing connection to www.somesite.com:443.
```

and I closed that tty.

What should I do to make it continue?

**Here is a part of wget output:**

```
www.somesite.com/.../sport.html       [   <=>                                           ] 833.32K  1.53MB/s    in 0.5s    
Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.
2018-02-10 16:34:23 (1.53 MB/s) - ‘www.somesite.com/.../sport.html’ saved [853319]

--2018-02-10 16:34:23--  http://www.somesite.com/.../social
Reusing existing connection to www.somesite.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘www.somesite.com/.../social.html’

www.somesite.com/.../social.html      [ <=>                                             ] 141.35K   816KB/s    in 0.2s    

Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.
2018-02-10 16:34:24 (816 KB/s) - ‘www.somesite.com/.../social.html’ saved [144747]

--2018-02-10 16:34:24--  http://www.somesite.com/.../parliament
Reusing existing connection to www.somesite.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘www.somesite.com/.../parliament.html’
```

The command I used is:

```
wget -m -c -p -E -k -np -e robots=off https://www.somesite.com
```

Is there no way to instruct wget to not download the same url that it had already downloaded before?

Comment: What should I do to make it continue? I remember the last thing it said was awaiting respone... and then nothing. but now I've closed that tty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the command again. `wget` is clever enough to continue the download. However, you must specify correct options.

For example, remove the `-nc` option if you want to re-download changed files (see also [Skip download if files exist in wget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944295/skip-download-if-files-exist-in-wget)):

> ```
> -nc
> --no-clobber
> ```
>
> (…) When -nc is specified, (…) Wget will refuse to download newer copies of file.  Therefore, ""no-clobber"" is actually a misnomer in this mode---it's not clobbering that's prevented (as the numeric suffixes were already preventing clobbering), but rather the multiple version saving that's prevented.
>
> When running Wget with -r or -p, but without -N, -nd, or -nc, re-downloading a file will result in the new copy simply overwriting the old.  Adding -nc will prevent this behavior, instead causing the original version to be preserved and any newer copies on the server to be ignored.

If the download was interrupted during downloading a large file, you might want to add the `-c` option:

> ```
> -c
> --continue
> ```
>
> Continue getting a partially-downloaded file.  This is useful when you want to finish
>              up a download started by a previous instance of Wget, or by another program.

Source of quotes: [`man wget`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html)

You should also consider using `screen` or `tmux` instead of `disown` to be able to check the status and output of your background processes.

Comment: Are you sure wget will continue? I thought it will follow all the links again from the begining and just load the local files instead of downloading them if the local files exist.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay It does the best it can. You should definitely read the man page. “Wget has been designed for robustness over slow or unstable network connections; if a download fails due to a network problem, it will keep retrying until the whole file has been retrieved. If the server supports regetting, it will instruct the server to continue the download from where it left off.“

Comment: Please note that I'm not downloading a file. I'm mirroring a large website and I've already downloaded 130k files. I'm afraid if I kill wget and restart it it will have to recheck and process all those files which will take a large time.

Comment: Yes, it would recheck the files but it won’t redownload them if the server can provide timestamps of those files to check whether they have been changed.

Comment: that is my problem. As I've said I've already downloaded more than 300000 files. And checking all of them will take a very long time.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay Probably not the amount of time that elapsed since you asked this question… Anyway, is your `wget` process still running or has it stopped?

Comment: it has stopped. I tried to run it again and I realized that It was downloading so many things(in the network monitor) but du -s told me that nth was being added to the directory. so I stopped it again.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay Are you sure it was downloading? Wasn’t it just re-checking as I have mentioned?

Comment: my network monitor in ubuntu said that so much things were being downloading(1GB) and I was not downloading anything at all in the meanwhile. also the wget output was showing download progressbar all the time. I'll paste a bit of the output here now.

Comment: The output shows that the server does not support time-stamps (which would allow skipping unchanged files) or the webpages you are trying to download are generated dynamically.

Comment: Yes they are being generated dynamically but the same url will give the same page. Is there no way to instruct wget to not download the same url that it had already downloaded before?

Comment: If you have no problem that changed pages won’t be re-downloaded, then use your `-nc` option, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4944295/711006. And please add _all_ details on your requirements to your question.